# Geoserver Layer limits

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql

Is their the effective layer limit for a Geoserver instance running on Ubuntu Linux 16.04?  I assume that each layer translates to a Postgres table, and while I have read that there is no real limit by Postgres on number tables per instance, there are [some limits imposed by OS and performance considerations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3715621/1088561). What count of layers in GeoServer might you begin to experience performance problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there are definite answers, but in terms of layers numbers there is this GeoServer Improvement Proposal giving some numbers:

https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/GSIP-155

and then this thread:

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Some-follow-up-to-GSIP-155-with-a-larger-data-dir-td5307534.html

Long story short, if you are using GeoServer 2.12.0 on-wards, you are probably fine handling < 50000 layers (note the benchmarking machine was 8 years old and using a spinning disk, using modern hardware you'd get better results).